# HTML: Making link editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an angular page that I display a series of links on from a list. Here's the HTML/Angular code:

```
<li role="menuitem"
    ng-repeat="foo in foos track by $index"
    ng-click="selectFoo(foo)">
    <a href="#">
        {{foo}}
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want the user to be able to edit the display name of foo by clicking on the glyphicon. I could do this pretty easily by adding an `ng-click` component to the `<span>` and opening up a modal with a text input etc etc.

But I want to do it in a more streamlined manner. Is it possible to have the glyphicon click change the link into a text input where the user can type something, hit enter and finish editing. I don't want to make the `<a>` into a text input because clicking on it does another action. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AngularJS to switch between showing `{{foo}}` and showing an `<input>` that is binded to `foo`:

```
<li role="menuitem"
    ng-repeat="foo in foos track by $index">
  <span data-ng-hide="foo.isEditing" data-ng-model="foo"></span>
  <input type="text" data-ng-show="foo.isEditing" data-ng-model="foo">
  <a data-ng-click="foo.isEditing = !foo.isEditing" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

So when a user clicks the `glyphicon` then it should toggle the state of `foo.isEditing` from `false` to `true` or vice-versa. Both `span` and `input` are binded to `foo` via `ng-model` so updates to `foo` happen instantaneously. Let me know if this works out for ya, cheers!

Comment: I tried this out but this was firing the li element's on-click function even thought I was clicking directly on the glyphicon element. Any way to define the click area.

Comment: You'll need to remove the `ng-click` from the `li` element because that binds a click event to the entire element's space. If you need to bind that click event somewhere, maybe bind it to the `<span>` element instead so if a user clicks on the text then that will trigger the click.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the *contentEditable* property on your targeted *span* element should be the simplest solution one may desire. e.g.:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right" contentEditable="true"></span>
```

Also, controlling it (most probably by implementing an on/off toggle ) through your script, would be as easy.